# Order a table by a column in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have looked at other questions/answer regarding my question, but for some reason, every time I try to implement an answer exactly how they implemented it, it throws an error. But I am paginating some things now, and I need to order my results by column in another table.

Here is the code I have now:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`players`,`max_players`,`status`,`host`,`port` 
  FROM `servers` 
 LIMIT :to,:from
```

The table it is getting stuff from is the `servers` table, and it needs to get the column `rank` from the `server_profiles` table, and order it by that. I try to understand how MySQL joins work, but they always seem to confuse me, from looking at examples, to reading the markup on the MySQL wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join for that. For that you need to have a relation between both tables. I have used `server.ID = server_profiles.serversID` for example.

```
SELECT s.* FROM servers s
  JOIN server_profiles sp
    ON s.ID = sp.serversID
 ORDER BY sp.rank
 LIMIT :to,:from
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9928e/1)

Comment: So in the `server_profiles` table, the ID in that table is `server_profiles.id` and it gives me the error saying `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous` Does this mean I need to rename the ID column in server_profiles?

Comment: @TheNytangel - No. You don't need to do that. Just add alias in your SELECT statement before any column name like this: `SELECT s.id, s.name,...`